# How to stop the ng serve in the mac terminal as Cmd + C doesn't work

Tags: angular, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, macos-catalina

I have the following setup for Angular below. I am using an external monitor that switches between a Win10 machine and a MacBook pro running Catalina. I use my Win10 for work a lot and thus have a single Windows external USB keyboard.

I have configured the keys on the keyboard to run as close to what I am used to with Win as shown in the screenshot.

Now when using Angular I cannot end the `ng serve --open` in the terminal without closing the terminal. I have tried all the Cmd + C once and twice and adding shirt and a period but still nothing.

[image]

Do I need to reconfigure the keys a bit?

Obviously I don't have a Command or Option key but a Windows key instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit `command + .` or `control^ + c` or `control + z`.

Comment: The first one worked which is Ctrl/Cmd + . which I guess I missed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In recent angular-cli version `q + enter` stops the server.